# .htacess rewrite from view/index.php?id=123 to /view/123

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a directory named `view`. Within there I have index.php.

Currently, users have to go to `mydomain.com/account/new/prescriptions/view/index.php?id=61312` to view the data.

How can i use .htaccess to change this to `mydomain.com/account/new/prescriptions/view/61312`

I have tried the below:

```
# Specific rewrite for account/new/prescriptions/view
RewriteRule ^(account/new/prescriptions/view)/(\d+)$ $1 [END]

# Append .php extension for other requests
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [END]
```

However, this changes the url to from `index.php?id=61312` to `index?id=61312`

Comment: "this changes the url" - what does that mean? Usually, these rules don't change the URL, but how it is processed

Comment: You've apparently already heard of rewrite rules, and maybe read some information about them; so I find it surprising that you have come across one of the literally thousands of pages that explain **exactly this use case**. It's a bit like knowing something about the alphabet, but not the letter "a".

Comment: One tip I will give you, which I don't think is mentioned often enough, is this: **rewrite rules don't make ugly URLs pretty, they make pretty URLs functional**. The starting point is always what shows in the browser; what you are doing is telling the server what patterns to look for, and what to do when it sees them. Keeping that straight will avoid a lot of common mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this code inside `view/.htaccess`:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

# rewrite for /path/123 to /path/index.php?id=123
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [END,QSA]

# Append .php extension for other requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [END]
```

Comment: Thanks. does this .htaccess go inside the `view` directory?

Comment: Try my updated code in `view/.htaccess`.